# Why doesn't my mouse work in Gnome-shell at 30-bit color depth?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, mouse, color-depth

Title pretty much says it. Keyboard shortcuts are fine. But the mouse interaction, Clicking on anything but desktop icons is... not happening.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu 12.04? Which graphics card do you have? Does it support 30-bit/32-bit colour depth? Does the monitor support 30-/32-bit colour depth? Does it happen on all programs? There's some info about 30-bit for nvidia: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/295.40/README/depth30.html

Comment: 12.04, Gtx250, gpu supports, monitor supports, no it doesnt happen in all, and allll righty then.

Comment: Could you mention which apps are in question? Try running them in a terminal, maybe there's some debug information. According to the link I mentioned above, some apps might not work.

Comment: apps in question is the gnome shell, mouse interactivity failure.<br> keyboard works. (pure guess) The mouse is redered seperately and is not interacting at the same visual layer.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL now. VTC this unanswered question as `not reproducible`